# data.map q se carga con useEffect me da NULL al redireccionar la página react?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un problema, tengo un useEffect, donde hago varias peticiones a una API...

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState(null);
const [brands, setMarcas] = useState(null);
const [rubros, setRubros] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {   
    const producto = new Productos();
    const rubro = new RubrosServicios();
    const marca = new MarcasServicios();
    producto.getProducts().then(data => setProducts(data));
    rubro.getRubro().then(data => setRubros(data)); 
    marca.getMarca().then(data => setMarcas(data));  
}, []);
```

Cuando entro directamente al componente("/catalogo"), me hace 4 veces las peticiones(lo compruebo imprimiendo en consola, "products, brands, rubros")...

Primero me imprime los 3 arrays como "null", luego imprime el 1ero con datos(products), y el segundo y tercero(brands y rubros) null, luego, me imprime products y brands con datos y rubros "null"..

estoy me genera un problema en un map que hago un return que está dentro de una clase.

```
class Marcas extends React.Component {  
                   
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: 'coconut'};
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }        
    handleChange(event) {     
        localStorage.setItem('marcafiltrada', event.target.value)
        class CargarMarcasFiltro{
            getMarcaFiltro() {
                return axios.get(UrlGral+'productos/?filtrarmarca=1&marca='+event.target.value+'&llave='+localStorage.getItem('llave')).then(res => res.data);
            }
        }
        
        const marcaFiltro = new CargarMarcasFiltro();
        marcaFiltro.getMarcaFiltro().then(data => setProducts(data));   
        /* this.setState({value: event.target.value});  
        event.preventDefault(); */
    }        
    render() {
        return (
                <select value={localStorage.getItem('marcafiltrada')}  onChange={this.handleChange}> 
                    <option value="1">Todas las marcas</option>                                    
                   {brands.filter(marca => marca.nombre != "").map((marca) => (                                        
                        <option 
                        label={marca.nombre}
                        value={marca.id}
                        >{marca.nombre}
                        </option>
                    ))}
                </select>
        );
    }
}
```

Cuando cargo por primera vez el proyecto(npm start), me carga bien el combo de "brands"... luego, cuando navego dentro del proyecto, y vuelvo a regresar al componente "/catalogo", me salta el error de que no se puede utilizar la funcion ".map()" ya que "brands" es un array "null"...

Alguna solución? o algo q esté haciendo mal?

Comment: Parece que se necesita implementar algún patrón de Promesas para manejar esas peticiones API, si pudieras compartir el código del componente donde usas el useEffect, supongo que el child/leaf component es Marcas, esa parte no esta clara.

Answer (score 0):

Haz probado removiendo el (null) de dentro de los paréntesis en la declaración de los useState?

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState();
const [brands, setMarcas] = useState();
const [rubros, setRubros] = useState();
```

Comment: Como estás? gracias por la respuesta. He probado eso, y no, me sigue ocurriendo el mismo problema.